# Generic factory mechanism in C++17

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, c++17, factory

I would like to implement a generic factory mechanism for a set of derived classes that allows me to generically implement not only a factory function to create objects of that class, but also creators of other template classes which take as template arguments one of the derived classes.

Ideally a solution would only use C++17 features (no dependencies).

Consider this example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

struct Foo {
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
    virtual void hello() = 0;
};

struct FooA: Foo { 
    static constexpr char const* name = "A";
    void hello() override { std::cout << "Hello " << name << std::endl; }
};

struct FooB: Foo { 
    static constexpr char const* name = "B";
    void hello() override { std::cout << "Hello " << name << std::endl; }
};

struct FooC: Foo { 
    static constexpr char const* name = "C";
    void hello() override { std::cout << "Hello " << name << std::endl; }
};

struct BarInterface {
    virtual ~BarInterface() = default;
    virtual void world() = 0;
};

template <class T>
struct Bar: BarInterface {
    void world() { std::cout << "World " << T::name << std::endl; }
};

std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo_factory(const std::string& name) {
    if (name == FooA::name) {
        return std::make_unique<FooA>();
    } else if (name == FooB::name) {
        return std::make_unique<FooB>();
    } else if (name == FooC::name) {
        return std::make_unique<FooC>();
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}

std::unique_ptr<BarInterface> bar_factory(const std::string& foo_name) {
    if (foo_name == FooA::name) {
        return std::make_unique<Bar<FooA>>();
    } else if (foo_name == FooB::name) {
        return std::make_unique<Bar<FooB>>();
    } else if (foo_name == FooC::name) {
        return std::make_unique<Bar<FooC>>();
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto foo = foo_factory("A");
    foo->hello();
    auto bar = bar_factory("C");
    bar->world();
}
```

[run it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7GGpruXD9mQAunMs)

I am looking for a mechanism that would allow me to implement both `foo_factory` and `bar_factory` without listing all classes, such that they do not need to be updated once I add for example `FooD` as an additional derived class. Ideally, the different Foo derivatives would somehow "self-register", but listing them all in one central place is also acceptable.

**Edit:**

Some clarifications based on comments / answers:

- It is necessary in my case to invoke the factories with (something like) a string, since the callers of the factories use polymorphism with `Foo` / `BarInterface`, i.e. they don't know about the concrete derived classes. On the other hand in Bar we want to use template methods of the derived Foo classes and facilitate inlining, that's why we really need the templated derived `Bar` classes (rather than accessing Foo objects through some base-class interface).
- We can assume that all derived Foo classes are defined in one place (and a manual registration where we list them all once in the same place is therefore acceptable, if necessary). However, they do not know about the existence of Bar, and in fact we have multiple different classes like `BarInterface` and `Bar`. So we cannot create "constructor objects" of Bar and save them in a map the same way we can do it for a `foo_factory`. What  I think is needed is some kind of "compile-time map" (or list) of all the derived Foo types, such that when defining the bar_factory, the compiler can iterate over them, but I don't know how to do that...

**Edit2:**

Additional constraints that proofed to be relevant [during discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045367/generic-factory-mechanism-in-c17#comment96874247_55053138):

- **Templates and template templates:** The Foo are actually templates (with a single class argument) and the Bar are template templates taking a concrete Foo as template argument. The Foo templates have no specializations and all have the same "name", so querying any concrete type is fine. In particular `SpecificFoo<double>::name` is always valid. @Julius' answer has been extended to facilitate this already. For @Yakk's the same can probably be done (but it will take me some time for figure it out in detail).
- **Flexible bar factory code:** The factory for Bar does a little more than just call the constructor. It also passes some arguments and does some type casting (in particular, it may have Foo references that should be `dynamic_cast` to the corresponding concrete derived Foo). Therefore a solution that allows to write this code inline during definition of the bar_factory seems most readable to me. @Julius' answer works great here, even if the loop code with tuples is a little verbose.
- **Making the "single place" listing the Foos even simpler:** From the answers so far I believe the way to go for me is having a compile-time list of foo types and a way to iterate over them. There are two answers that define a list of Foo types (or templates) in one central place (either with a `types` template or with tuples), which is already great. However, for other reasons I already have in the same central place a list of macro calls, one for each foo, like `DECLARE_FOO(FooA, "A") DECLARE_FOO(FooB, "B") ...`. Can the declaration of `FooTypes` be somehow take advantage of that, so I don't have to list them again? I guess such type lists cannot be declared iteratively (appending to an already existing list), or can it? In the absence of that, probably with some macro magic it would be possible. Maybe always redefining and thus appending to a preprocessor list in the `DECLARE_FOO` calls, and then finally some "iterate over loop" to define the `FooTypes` type list. IIRC boost preprocessor has facilities to loop over lists (although I don't want a boost dependency).

For some more `context`, you can think of the different Foo and it's template argument as classes similar to `Eigen::Matrix<Scalar>` and the Bar are cost functors to be used with Ceres. The bar factory returns objects like `ceres::AutoDiffCostFunction<CostFunctor<SpecificFoo>, ...>` as `ceres::CostFunction*` pointers.

**Edit3:**

Based on @Julius' answer I created a solution that works with Bars that are templates as well as template templates. I suspect one could unify `bar_tmpl_factory` and `bar_ttmpl_factory` into one function using variadic variadic template templates (is that a thing?).

[run it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/586112bbc0d201bb)

<s>*TODO:*</s>

- <s>combine `bar_tmpl_factory` and `bar_ttmpl_factory`</s>
- <s>the point `Making the "single place" listing the Foos even simpler` from above</s>
- <s>maybe replacing the use of tuples with @Yakk's `types` template (but in a way such that the creator function can be defined inline at the call site of the loop over all foo types).</s>

*I consider the question answered and if anything the above points should be separate questions.*

Comment: `static` `std::map<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<Foo>()>>` and register near derived classes ?

Comment: But it's necessary pass through a `std::string` identifier of the derived class? What about passing it as template type (`foo_factory<FooA>()` and `bar_factory<FooA>()`)?

Comment: @Jarod42, that would work for `foo_factory`, but not `bar_factory`, right? Note that there are multiple different `BarInterface` like classes that I need factories for.

Comment: @max66 yes, it needs to work with something like passing a string (or possibly a polymorphic `Foo*` pointer). The caller of bar_factory does not know about the derived Foo classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I think is needed is some kind of "compile-time map" (or list) of
>   all the derived Foo types, such that when defining the bar_factory,
>   the compiler can iterate over them, but I don't know how to do that...

Here is one basic option:

```
#include <cassert>

#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

#include "foo_and_bar_without_factories.hpp"

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<std::size_t... indices, class LoopBody>
void loop_impl(std::index_sequence<indices...>, LoopBody&& loop_body) {
  (loop_body(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, indices>{}), ...);
}

template<std::size_t N, class LoopBody>
void loop(LoopBody&& loop_body) {
  loop_impl(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, std::forward<LoopBody>(loop_body));
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

using FooTypes = std::tuple<FooA, FooB, FooC>;// single registration

std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo_factory(const std::string& name) {
  std::unique_ptr<Foo> ret{};

  constexpr std::size_t foo_count = std::tuple_size<FooTypes>{};

  loop<foo_count>([&] (auto i) {// `i` is an std::integral_constant
    using SpecificFoo = std::tuple_element_t<i, FooTypes>;
    if(name == SpecificFoo::name) {
      assert(!ret && "TODO: check for unique names at compile time?");
      ret = std::make_unique<SpecificFoo>();
    }
  });

  return ret;
}

std::unique_ptr<BarInterface> bar_factory(const std::string& name) {
  std::unique_ptr<BarInterface> ret{};

  constexpr std::size_t foo_count = std::tuple_size<FooTypes>{};

  loop<foo_count>([&] (auto i) {// `i` is an std::integral_constant
    using SpecificFoo = std::tuple_element_t<i, FooTypes>;
    if(name == SpecificFoo::name) {
      assert(!ret && "TODO: check for unique names at compile time?");
      ret = std::make_unique< Bar<SpecificFoo> >();
    }
  });

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That looks very much what I wanted. Maybe not as elegant as @Yakk's answer, but for me it is much more readable. Compile-time-check for uniqueness in the names would be fancy, but its really not needed. Other things will also break badly if this is violated (and the number of Foo derivatives is not huge).

Comment: Works great for what I described. I have another case where the Foo derivatives are template classes and Bar is a template template. I can define FooTypes as a template no problem, but when I try to implement the loop, the `template<class T> using SpecificFoo = std::tuple_element_t<i, FooTypes<T>>;` doesn't work, since it is at block scope. Can I somehow have a tuple of templates and iterate over them (in a way that i can instantiate the template template Bar with the template SpecificFoo)?

Comment: @NikolausDemmel: Can we assume that the template template parameters match `template<class...> class`? If they have non-type arguments it becomes tricky. However, each non-type argument can be wrapped in a type.

Comment: Yes, you can in fact assume `template<class T> struct FooA ...` and `template<template <class> class FooType1, template <class> class FooType2, ...> Bar`. PS: the `...` are just meant as casual "and so on", not actual C++ variadic `...`.

Comment: @NikolausDemmel: You may wrap the `Foo` templates into tag types of the form `template<template<class...> class Tmpl> struct TemplateTag {};`. Then you can treat the templates (represented by their tags) just as normal types. Similarly, it is often useful to wrap non-type template parameters such as `int` and `std::size_t` in a `std::integral_constant`. I tried to create [an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08783ea415f39ac4), but I am not sure which template argument should be used for, say, `FooA` when asking for its name.

Comment: PS: When asking for the name I'm using a fixed known-to-be-valid template argument, namely `double` in my case. There are no template specializations for Foo and the name is the same regardless of the template argument.

Comment: I updated the question with this requirement. Could you please append your updated solution form your comment to your answer, because I think it is very helpful and instructive. Maybe leave the original simple version without template templates intact for future readers. Thanks!

Comment: @NikolausDemmel: Good to know that you can solve your problems now. I also appreciate your enormous effort in sharing your insights. However, I think it is more useful to keep each SO question focussed on one particular problem. I posted a new question and self-answered it with the code linked to from my comment. https://stackoverflow.com/q/55090524/2615118

Comment: Makes sense. For future readers isolated questions with concise answers make more sense than some "and then this happened, and then that" story. I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 4):

```
template<class...Ts>struct types_t {};
template<class...Ts>constexpr types_t<Ts...> types{};
```

that lets us work with bundles of types without the overhead of a tuple.

```
template<class T>
struct tag_t { using type=T;
  template<class...Ts>
  constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(Ts&&...ts)const {
    return T{}(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }
};
template<class T>
constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};
```

this lets us work with types as values.

Now a type tag map is a function that takes a type tag, and returns another type tag.

```
template<template<class...>class Z>
struct template_tag_map {
  template<class In>
  constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(In in_tag)const{
    return tag< Z< typename decltype(in_tag)::type > >;
  }
};
```

this takes a template type map and makes it into a tag map.

```
template<class R=void, class Test, class Op, class T0 >
R type_switch( Test&&, Op&& op, T0&&t0 ) {
  return static_cast<R>(op(std::forward<T0>(t0)));
}

template<class R=void, class Test, class Op, class T0, class...Ts >
auto type_switch( Test&& test, Op&& op, T0&& t0, Ts&&...ts )
{
  if (test(t0)) return static_cast<R>(op(std::forward<T0>(t0)));
  return type_switch<R>( test, op, std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
}
```

that lets us test a condition on a bunch of types, and run an operation on the one that "succeeds".

```
template<class R, class maker_map, class types>
struct named_factory_t;

template<class R, class maker_map, class...Ts>
struct named_factory_t<R, maker_map, types_t<Ts...>>
{
  template<class... Args>
  auto operator()( std::string_view sv, Args&&... args ) const {
    return type_switch<R>(
      [&sv](auto tag) { return decltype(tag)::type::name == sv; },
      [&](auto tag) { return maker_map{}(tag)(std::forward<Args>(args)...); },
      tag<Ts>...
    );
  }
};
```

now we want to make shared pointers of some template class.

```
struct shared_ptr_maker {
  template<class Tag>
  constexpr auto operator()(Tag ttag) {
    using T=typename decltype(ttag)::type;
    return [](auto&&...args){ return std::make_shared<T>(decltype(args)(args)...); };
  }
};
```

so that makes shared pointers given a type.

```
template<class Second, class First>
struct compose {
  template<class...Args>
  constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&...args) const {
    return Second{}(First{}( std::forward<Args>(args)... ));
  }
};
```

now we can compose function objects at compile time.

Next wire it up.

```
using Foos = types_t<FooA, FooB, FooC>;
constexpr named_factory_t<std::shared_ptr<Foo>, shared_ptr_maker, Foos> make_foos;

constexpr named_factory_t<std::shared_ptr<BarInterface>, compose< shared_ptr_maker, template_tag_map<Bar> >, Foos> make_bars;
```

and [Done](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42b9d89c143dd3f4).

The original design was actually [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) with lambdas instead of those `struct`s for `shared_ptr_maker` and the like.

Both `make_foos` and `make_bars` have zero runtime state.

Comment: Thanks for this! The result looks very elegant, quite amazing! It'll take me some time to understand fully and mold into what I need in the actual code.

Comment: Hm... I thought I made the following comment already, but it seems it disappeared or I never posted it properly: Currently with this solution, passing an invalid name to the factory gives you the "last" foo type in the list. I guess the correct way to handle it would be augmenting the `type_switch` base case to also check `op` and in fase it is false take appropriate measures (return null, through exceptions, ...), right?

Comment: @nikolaus Yes.  Or have a fallback "default" operation passed to it.

Answer (score 2):

Write a generic factory like the following that allows registration at the class site:

```
template <typename Base>
class Factory {
public:
    template <typename T>
    static bool Register(const char * name) {
       get_mapping()[name] = [] { return std::make_unique<T>(); };
       return true;
    }
    static std::unique_ptr<Base> factory(const std::string & name) {
        auto it = get_mapping().find(name);
        if (it == get_mapping().end())
            return {};
        else
            return it->second();
    }

private:
    static std::map<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<Base>()>> & get_mapping() {
        static std::map<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<Base>()>> mapping;
        return mapping;
    }
};
```

And then use it like:

```
struct FooA: Foo {
    static constexpr char const* name = "A";
    inline static const bool is_registered = Factory<Foo>::Register<FooA>(name);
    inline static const bool is_registered_bar = Factory<BarInterface>::Register<Bar<FooA>>(name);
    void hello() override { std::cout << "Hello " << name << std::endl; }
};
```

and

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> foo_factory(const std::string& name) {
    return Factory<Foo>::factory(name);
}
```

**Note:** there is no way to guarantee that the class would be registered. The compiler might decide not to include the translation unit, if there are no other dependencies. It is probably better to simply register all classes in one central place. Also note that the self-registering implementation depends on inline variables (C++17). It is not a strong dependence, and it is possible to get rid of it by declaring the booleans in the header and defining them in the CPP (which makes self-registering uglier and more prone to failing to register).

## edit

1. The disadvantage of this answer, when compared to others, is that it performs the registration during start-up and not during compilation. On the other hand, this makes the code much simpler.
2. The examples above assume that the definition of `Bar<T>` is moved above `Foo`. If that is impossible, then the registration can be done in an initialization function, in a cpp:

   ```
   // If possible, put at the header file and uncomment:
   // inline
   const bool barInterfaceInitialized = [] {
      Factory<Foo>::Register<FooA>(FooA::name);
      Factory<Foo>::Register<FooB>(FooB::name);
      Factory<Foo>::Register<FooC>(FooC::name);
      Factory<BarInterface>::Register<Bar<FooA>>(FooA::name);
      Factory<BarInterface>::Register<Bar<FooB>>(FooB::name);
      Factory<BarInterface>::Register<Bar<FooC>>(FooC::name);
      return true;
   }();
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my case that would work for `foo_factory`, but not for `bar_factory`, since `Bar` is not known at the place where the `Foo` are defined, and there are many different classes like `Bar`, that I would need to all register independently. Sorry, I'll clarify this constraint in the question.

Comment: @NikolausDemmel I have added a note that shows the way registration can be done in a separate function(s)

Comment: Thanks for the update. The situation is more like Foo is in one library and there might be many different BarInterface / Bar's in other libraries, so when I add or change a Foo, I don't even know all the places I might have to update. I agree about he code being much simpler and it is an instructive answer for me, but I think I some of the other answers fit my use case better. Regardless, I appreciate you taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

In C++17, we can apply the fold expression to simplify the storing process of generating functions `std::make_unique<FooA>()`, `std::make_unique<FooB>()`, and so on into the factory class in this case.

---

To begin with, for convenience, let us define the following type alias `Generator` which describes the type of each generating function `[](){ return std::make_unique<T>(); }`:

```
template<typename T>
using Generator = std::function<std::unique_ptr<T>(void)>;
```

Next, we define the following rather generic functor `createFactory` which returns each factory as a hash map `std::unordered_map`.
Here I apply the fold expression with the comma operators.
For instance, `createFactory<BarInterface, Bar, std::tuple<FooA, FooB, FooC>>()()` returns the hash map corresponding to your function `bar_factory`:

```
template<typename BaseI, template<typename> typename I, typename T>
void inserter(std::unordered_map<std::string_view, Generator<BaseI>>& map)
{
    map.emplace(T::name, [](){ return std::make_unique<I<T>>(); });
}

template<typename BaseI, template<typename> class I, typename T>
struct createFactory {};

template<typename BaseI, template<typename> class I, typename... Ts>
struct createFactory<BaseI, I, std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    auto operator()()
    {
        std::unordered_map<std::string_view, Generator<BaseI>> map;
        (inserter<BaseI, I, Ts>(map), ...);
    
        return map;
    }
};
```

This functor enables us to list `FooA, FooB, FooC, ...` all in one central place as follows:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U0B0ke5XGrwzj4TO) (I also added virtual destructors in base classes)

```
template<typename T>
using NonInterface = T;

// This can be written in one central place.
using FooTypes = std::tuple<FooA, FooB, FooC>;

int main()
{    
    const auto foo_factory = createFactory<Foo, NonInterface, FooTypes>()();
    const auto foo = foo_factory.find("A");
    if(foo != foo_factory.cend()){
        foo->second()->hello();
    }
        
    const auto bar_factory = createFactory<BarInterface, Bar, FooTypes>()();
    const auto bar = bar_factory.find("C");
    if(bar != bar_factory.cend()){
        bar->second()->world();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I like the generic nature of this a lot and it would allow me to simplify some code already, but it's not quite yet what I would ideally want. I wasn't clear about constraints on the "central place" for listing the Foos once (sorry, I updated the question now). It should be such that this central place is before the definition of any of the Bars, i.e. in you case the `Factory` template class would need to work without knowledge of anything about Bar (and in fact there are multiple classes like BarInterface / Bar for which I want to create something like `bar_factory`).

Comment: Thanks for the update. I see now how it works with a type list of the Foos that is only defined once. The bit about the fold expression and the comma operator is interesting, I think I would not have thought of that! Compared to Julius' and Yakk's answers the advantage here is maybe that the generic code is simpler, if all you want to do is creating those runtime maps of constructors, that you can then manipulate with non-templated code.

Comment: @NikolausDemmel thx again. If you want to recursively create the instances of `Foo`, `BarIF`,... and `BazIF` with `FooA`, `FooB`,... and `FooZ` again and again, the hash map would provide a performance effective way. **I thought that the advantage of my answer is not only the readability, but also this point.** Since similar situation happens a lot at least in my experience, so I just made this assumption about it :). If not, sorry. If so, verbosely writing each map definition should be avoided. The above function can simply describe these construction and thus I posted it.

Comment: I get it now, if you have many Foo and different kinds of BarIF all over the place, a map can provide benefit. However, if you want to implement things with FooTypes, you need to still know all Foos before you can define it.